# Why is ZIPing a file slower the first time?

Tags: windows, cordova, zip, phonegap

I have a Cordova project that I am uploading to PhoneGap Build. In order to do so, I need to upload a ZIP file of the project. I have noticed an interesting but probably explainable phenomenon. The first time I compress (using Windows' built in `Send To` > `Compressed (zipped) folder`) the project for the day, it takes its time. Each time after that, when I recompress it, having changed some of my source, it zips through it (pun intended).

I would have thought that a quick Google search would have revealed some built in optimization on Windows end for compressing, but I probably just don't know what to search for.